# Is 「出なくては。」 the same as 「出なくてはいけない。」?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I guess the novel I'm reading (「キッチン」 by 吉本ばなな) will be a source of many questions.

The part I want to ask about now is the passage where the main character is thinking about moving house. The passage is the record of her thoughts and contains some sentences that are not complete. In two places she's thinking:

> でも、ここを出なくては。

and later

> 出なくては。

I'm guessing maybe 「出なくては。」 is a shortened, incomplete form and normally has something after は. Is it the same as 「出なくてはいけない。」 and the meaning is "I have to leave"?

<sub>(Let me know if I need to post more to give context.)</sub>

Comment: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13812/%E9%9A%A0%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A6-is-this-correct/13813#13813

Comment: @snailboat Haven't noticed that one. So I guess my question should be closed as duplicate.